# Netbeans declarative hint syntax for a statement inside a try-block

Tags: java, netbeans, refactoring

I'd like to *inspect and transform* a specific statement into a try-with-ressources form. But I have the feeling the syntax of the [declarative hints format](http://wiki.netbeans.org/JavaDeclarativeHintsFormat) eludes me for this.

I tried:

```
<!description="Stmt into try-with-resources">
try {
  $before$;
  someMethod($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
  $after$;
 } catch $catches$
=>
try (Resource res = acquire($arg1, $arg2, $arg3))     {
  $before$;
  res.use();
  $after$;
} catch $catches$
```

But applied on my code the pattern  never matches. Here is some example code section which I expected to match:

```
public boolean step(String input) {
  String id = getId(ID);
  try {
    SomethingBefore();
    someMethod(10, "label", name);
    return true;
  } catch (Exception ex) {
    log.error("problem", ex);
    return true;
  }
}
```

Any idea why this does not match? Esp. because I think the example from the documentation matches mine, except for the `finally`:

```
try {
  $statements$;
} catch $catches$
  finally {
  $finally$;
}
```

*Update*: It seems that the [Jackpot](https://bitbucket.org/jlahoda/jackpot30/wiki/RulesLanguage)-Rules use the same syntax, probably because it uses the same code-base.

Answer (score 1):

This refactoring is very cumbersome and poorly documented. You must change your pattern according to this example

```
<!description="Stmt into try-with-resources">
try {
  $before$;
  $name($arg1, $arg2, $arg3);
  $after$;
 } catch $catches$
=>
try (Resource res = acquire($arg1, $arg2, $arg3))     {
  $before$;
  res.use();
  $after$;
} catch $catches$
```

However, I don't know how to handle this if you have other methods calling 3 arguments as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to me in the code return is being used which i dont think can be used in the place of $after$. So if you remove that from your code might match.